# Redirect folder only using htaccess, not pages in folder

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, directory

I have a link structure dynamically generated based on this:

http://www.website.com/profiles/

This page shows a listing of all profiles.

For filtering reasons, we also have

http://www.website.com/profile-category/categoryA/

This would only list the profiles of category A. However, when one removes the '/categoryA/' from this url, they get a 404 page not found.

I would like to redirect http://www.website.com/profile-category/ without http://www.website.com/profile-category/categoryA/ being affected. Is this possible using .htaccess?

I know the directory redirect in .htaccess, but this also affects all underlying pages.

Existing rewrite rules:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /

  RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Comment: Certainly it's possible. What existing .htaccess rules do you already have? (all of them)

Comment: ...and where do you want to redirect it to? `/profiles`?

Comment: Yes i'd like to redirect it to /profiles/. 
I only have wordpress permalink rules in .htaccess right now. I tried 
Redirect 301 /path/to-old-url    http://www.domain.com/path/to-new-url but that redirects all child pages as well.

Comment: Please _post_ your other rules. Wordpress in particular is finicky and it is important to get all your rules in the correct order.

Comment: Okay, I've added the rule you should need below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To ensure nothing following the bare directory path is matched, terminate it with a `$` and optionally allow a trailing slash with `/?`.  Order is very important with rewrite rules, so you must place this before WordPress's final catch-all rule.

First, test placing it before any of WordPress' rules. Failing that, insert it between them.

```
RewriteEngine On
# Redirect profile-category with nothing following to /profiles list
RewriteRule ^profile-category/?$ /profiles [L,R=301]

# Then WordPress
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /

  RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

I left WP's full block above because I'm not sure if it is dynamically written by the application (which could break your rule occasionally).  A more logical arrangement for the entire set of rules would be:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Never modify requests to index.php
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# Redirect profile-category with nothing following to /profiles list
RewriteRule ^profile-category/?$ /profiles [L,R=301]

# Wordpress - write all requests to non-existing files & dirs
# into index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

Comment: That worked brilliantly. Thank you so much!

Wordpress does not write the file dynamically. Its set for wordpress and won't be changed, so your second suggestion works as well.